# Java: Mediante Streams obtener la suma total de una propiedad de una lista de objetos

Tags: java, lista, java-stream

¿Cómo se puede obtener el total de los precios de todos los elementos de la lista productos usando *streams*?

```java
List<Producto> produtos = new ArrayList<Producto>();

produtos.add(new Producto(10));
produtos.add(new Producto(10));
produtos.add(new Producto(10));
produtos.add(new Producto(10));
produtos.add(new Producto(10));
```

El constructor de Producto recibe como parámetro único el precio del producto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se puede conseguir con la función `sum`, pero para ello primero debes de mapear los valores a ***int***, ***long*** o a ***double***.

Supongo que el precio de tu producto puede tener decimales, por lo que haremos un *map* del objeto con [Stream.mapToDouble](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)), el cual nos creará un [DoubleStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html), ya con ello podemos obtener la suma total con [DoubleStream.sum](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#sum()).

Para hacer el *map* a enteros está [Stream.mapToLong](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToLong(java.util.function.ToLongFunction)) y [Stream.mapToInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction))

Puedes hacer el map de la propiedad de un objeto con un *getter* o crear tu función lambda, cualquiera de las dos es válida.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        products.add(new Product("Product 1", 15.5));
        products.add(new Product("Product 2", 18));
        products.add(new Product("Product 3", 11.99));
        
        // Haciendo uso del getter, le pasamos la referencia
        // al método con los ::
        System.out.println(
                products.stream()
                .mapToDouble(Product::getPrice)
                .sum()
        );
       // Haciendo uso de una función lamba, le indicamos qué propiedad
       // usar para hacer el map
       System.out.println(
                products.stream()
                .mapToDouble(e -> e.price)
                .sum()
        );

    }

    private static class Product {
        private final String name;
        private final double price;

        public Product(String name, double price) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }

        public double getPrice() {
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, una ventaja del *getter* en mi opinión, es que puedes modularizar más tu código, pues si en un futuro necesitas modificar la operación de total, es más fácil y es mejor hacerlo en el mismo objeto. Como ejemplo te pongo que ahora hay un nuevo requerimiento y te piden que puedas comprar **n** productos a la vez. Le agregas la propiedad "cantidad" a tu objeto, y al método sólo una multiplicación.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

        products.add(new Product("Product 1", 15.5, 10));
        products.add(new Product("Product 2", 18, 2));
        products.add(new Product("Product 3", 11.99, 3));

        System.out.println(
                products.stream()
                .mapToDouble(Product::getTotal)
                .sum()
        );

    }

    private static class Product {
        private final String name;
        private final double price;
        private final int quantity;

        public Product(String name, double price, int quantity) {
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }

        public double getTotal() {
            return price * quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

Si se hiciera mediante funciones lambda, entonces tendrías que ir a cada pedazo de tu código buscando dónde usaste esa función, lo que lo hace menos mantenible.